# Generate UUID in Android Studio and use the same UUID after reinstalling the App

Tags: java, android, uuid, deviceid, android-identifiers

In this project that I'm working on, I want a unique ID for a Device that is using my App. I've decided to
use UUID (Universally Unique Identifier) in my project. Basically what I want is to assign this UUID to any files generated by my App.

**My Question:**
How can I store/save this UUID so that if my App is uninstalled the reinstalled later, the App can still use the same UUID that was generated during the previous installation?